# Custom image sizes are not used

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I recently launched a new theme and regenerated all the thumbnails with AJAX Rebuild. All of these custom image sizes are defined in my `functions.php` as well as the individual template files in which they are used. When I go and view source code my site, I don't see the new image sized appended to the end of the file name. I do however see the class name on the image that WordPress assigns is the new image size. I don't get what's going on!

**functions.php**

```
if (!function_exists('mytheme_setup')) {
    function mytheme_setup() {
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        add_image_size('homepage', 704, 396, true);
        add_image_size('articles', 1174, 660, true);
        add_image_size('in-post', 568, 320, true);
        add_image_size('featured-post', 1280, 683, true);
   }
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_setup' );
```

**Example of how I call it:**

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post_content'); ?>>
    <div class="social-drawer"></div>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php print_meta(); ?>
        <?php 
            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                the_post_thumbnail('in-post');
            } else { ?>
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/in-post-568x30-default.jpg" alt="All Features" />    
        <?php } ?>
    </a>
</article>
```

**Update**
I believe I discovered the issue. I did all of my image resizing on my staging site and then copied the resized images on staging to my production site (where I am currently experiencing these issues.) I have no learned that the DB references these image attachments and because I did not generate the sizes on Production, WordPress is unable to find the proper reference in the DB.

Comment: Provide a link to that plugin. Does your code work with any of the sized you added or is it limited to that `in-post` size?

Comment: Based on WP's documentation (scroll to bottom and see Resources) these are the plugins they recommended -- I've tried both Ajax Rebuild and Regen. Thumbnails: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: It's not using any of the custom sizes I generated on any of my templates,just the normal default image.

Comment: 1) I am not questioning the viability of the plugins. I wanted an easy way to see the source. It is just polite for the asker to provide that convenience. 2) If you aren't using the new sizes, exactly what is the problem? Sorry, that last comment of yours is confusing.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with some further information

Answer (score 0):

The `function.php`:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions   
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size('homepage', 704, 396, true);
    add_image_size('articles', 1174, 660, true);
    add_image_size('in-post', 568, 320, true);
    add_image_size('featured-post', 1280, 683, true);
}
```

To make it appear in .php-file:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'in-post' ); } ?>
```

That would be my suggestion.

Comment: The OP is already using `the_post_thumbnail( 'in-post' );` in the template files.

Comment: I am aware, but I believe the code he's using in his `function.php` is wrong. It might not be, but it just looks strange to me.

Comment: Did you test that your code behave correctly and the OP's doesn't? The OP's code looks like it should work to me, and it appears to be nicely encapsulated into an override-able function as well.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with some further information.